# Can we install RHEL5 on Poweredge r430?

Tags: redhat, dell-poweredge

We have a legacy software that needs RHEL 5.11 64bit to run. When I tried installing RHEL 5.11 I got the following error:

```
No Drives Found:
An error has occurred - no valid devices were found on which to create new filesystems. Please check your hardware for the cause of this problem.
```

Wondering if RHEL 5.11 64 bit is supported on a Dell Powerdege R430? If not, is there any work around? Did anyone experienced this before.

Comment: According to [Dell's OS support matrix](http://linux.dell.com/files/supportmatrix/RHEL_Support_Matrix.pdf), no it's not supported.  6.5 and higher or 7.0 and higher in 64 bit mode are what's supported.

Comment: Usual workaround: Use virtualization.

Comment: RHEL 6 and 7  have compatibility libraries to run most older software, but you have to actually install them. If that fails, you virtualize.